# Quick data population based on timestamp in R

Tags: r, matching

**Wishing you all Happy New Year**.

Coming to my question:

I have two datasets.

`Dataset 1`:

```
    Time            Name            Value
    6/1/2016 9:39   ABCD IS Equity  11.01
    6/1/2016 9:44   ABCD IS Equity  11.05
    6/1/2016 9:46   ABCD IS Equity  11.01
    6/1/2016 9:58   ABCD IS Equity  11.01
    6/1/2016 10:10  ABCD IS Equity  11.01
    6/1/2016 10:13  ABCD IS Equity  11.01
    6/1/2016 10:33  ABCD IS Equity  11.02
    6/1/2016 10:42  ABCD IS Equity  11.02
    6/1/2016 10:52  ABCD IS Equity  11.02
    6/1/2016 10:56  ABCD IS Equity  11.06
    6/1/2016 11:14  ABCD IS Equity  11.02
    6/1/2016 11:25  ABCD IS Equity  11.03
    6/1/2016 11:26  ABCD IS Equity  11.03
    6/1/2016 11:29  ABCD IS Equity  11.03
    6/1/2016 11:30  ABCD IS Equity  11.03
    6/1/2016 11:40  ABCD IS Equity  11.03
    6/1/2016 11:40  ABCD IS Equity  11.01
    6/1/2016 11:44  ABCD IS Equity  11.01
    6/1/2016 12:04  ABCD IS Equity  11.01
```

and `Dataset 2`:

```
Time2           Name2           Value2
6/1/2016 9:42   ABCD IS Equity  123
6/1/2016 9:45   ABCD IS Equity  124
6/1/2016 9:45   ABCD IS Equity  125
6/1/2016 10:00  ABCD IS Equity  126
6/1/2016 10:14  ABCD IS Equity  127
6/1/2016 10:14  ABCD IS Equity  128
6/1/2016 10:14  ABCD IS Equity  129
6/1/2016 10:41  ABCD IS Equity  130
6/1/2016 10:45  ABCD IS Equity  131
6/1/2016 10:56  ABCD IS Equity  132
6/1/2016 10:58  ABCD IS Equity  133
6/1/2016 11:26  ABCD IS Equity  134
6/1/2016 11:27  ABCD IS Equity  135
6/1/2016 11:30  ABCD IS Equity  136
6/1/2016 11:32  ABCD IS Equity  137
6/1/2016 11:40  ABCD IS Equity  138
6/1/2016 11:42  ABCD IS Equity  139
6/1/2016 11:45  ABCD IS Equity  140
6/1/2016 12:05  ABCD IS Equity  141
```

Now, I want to create a `New` Column in `Dataset 1` which will populate values from `Value2` of `Dataset2` based on condition `Dataset2$Time2 > Dataset1$Time` for each row of `Dataset 1`.

Below is the sample `output`:

```
Time            Name            Value   New
6/1/2016 9:39   ABCD IS Equity  11.01   123
6/1/2016 9:44   ABCD IS Equity  11.05   124
6/1/2016 9:46   ABCD IS Equity  11.01   126
6/1/2016 9:58   ABCD IS Equity  11.01   126
6/1/2016 10:10  ABCD IS Equity  11.01   127
6/1/2016 10:13  ABCD IS Equity  11.01   127
6/1/2016 10:33  ABCD IS Equity  11.02   130
6/1/2016 10:42  ABCD IS Equity  11.02   131
6/1/2016 10:52  ABCD IS Equity  11.02   132
6/1/2016 10:56  ABCD IS Equity  11.06   133
6/1/2016 11:14  ABCD IS Equity  11.02   134
6/1/2016 11:25  ABCD IS Equity  11.03   134
6/1/2016 11:26  ABCD IS Equity  11.03   135
6/1/2016 11:29  ABCD IS Equity  11.03   136
6/1/2016 11:30  ABCD IS Equity  11.03   137
6/1/2016 11:40  ABCD IS Equity  11.03   139
6/1/2016 11:40  ABCD IS Equity  11.01   139
6/1/2016 11:44  ABCD IS Equity  11.01   140
6/1/2016 12:04  ABCD IS Equity  11.01   141
```

Same value from column `Value2` may populate in different rows of `Dataset1` based on matching condition.

**Soln. I have tried:**

I have tried using simple `for` loop `[1: nrow(Dataset1)]` to match with each row of `Dataset2`. But I have a large dataset which is taking significant time. I am looking for much faster way - which can skip use of `for` loop.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: We can use `data.table` i.e. `setDT(df1)[df2, Value := Value2, on = .(Name, Time2 > Time1)]`

Comment: say if I have another common column named `Zone`. can I write like this for the `on` condition: `on = .(Name, Zone, Time2 > Time1)`

Comment: yes, you can do that

Comment: great, let me try

Comment: I have a feeling that you are looking for a rolling join. Somehting like `setDT(df2)[df, Value2, on = .(Time2 = Time), roll = -Inf]`. Also, you''ll need proper `POSIXct` classes in both tables first, e.g. `6/1/2016 12:04` has no meaning in R whatsoever

Comment: You may use `df2$Value2[findInterval(df1$Time, df2$Time2)+1]`

Comment: @David Arenburg POSIXct timestamp is fine in original data. and you meant to say `Time2 > Time` right?

Comment: I think akrun got it. And no, I didn't mean `Time2 > Time`. @akrun you can probably post that, will be very hard to beat that one.

Comment: `setDT(df1)[df2, Value := Value2, on = .(Name, Time2 > Time1)] ` is not working also. it is showing `'on' argument should be a named atomic vector oc column names indicating which columns in 'i' should be joined with which columns in 'x'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible option is `findInterval` from `base R`

```
 df2$New <- df2$Value2[findInterval(df1$Time, df2$Time2)+1]
```

NOTE: We assume that the 'Time', 'Time2' are `POSIXct` class

Comment: `timestamp` need to be sorted before applying the `findInterval`. working fine. gr8 solution indeed. thanks.